# List Selected Checkbox Options in Same p Tag - Using Svelte

Tags: html, css, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm currently learning how to use bindings in Svelte. I found this example that I am practicing with and would like to change the code slightly. I'm trying to make the selected items appear in 1 tag on the same line instead of multiple p tags for each option that is checked.

- If Roger and Syd are both selected then instead of listing Roger on one line and then Syd on another line underneath, I just wanted to have --> Roger, Syd (on same line in a single p tag).

I know I would just need to get ride of the each but I'm unsure of what I could use in place of it. I'd still like to keep this example as simple as possible. Here is the example:

```
  <script>
    let goodDogs = []
    let dogs = ['Roger', 'Syd']
</script>

<h2>
    Who's a good dog?
</h2>

<p>
    {#each dogs as dog}
        <p>{dog} <input type=checkbox bind:group={goodDogs} value={dog}></p>
    {/each}
</p>

<h2>
    Good dogs according to me:
</h2>

<p>
    {#each goodDogs as dog}
        <p>{dog}</p>
    {/each}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Svelte question, more of a general HTML question. That said, I think, if I understand you correctly, you would want to do something like the following, where you have your #each for dogs:

```html
<p>
    {#each dogs as dog}
            <span>{dog} <input type=checkbox bind:group={goodDogs} value={dog}></span>
    {/each}
</p>
```

What's happened is that we've swapped a block tag

(one which sits in it's own space), for an inline tag  (one which can sit alongside other tags). You can control these properties via CSS, but generally you shouldn't try to change an element's default display, it's more likely an indicator that you're using the wrong type of tag.

It's also worth noting that nesting

tags isn't recommended, and changing the outside tag to a  to contain the  elements is probably more appropriate.

Generally, you'd probably use an  for the purpose shown above, which is a tag for describing a list. You could then style the list to be horizontal instead of vertical - there are a number of tutorials for this online. Detail [about the ul tag can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

You may notice that your list is bunched up and too close together. You may consider adding padding to the list items (or span tags). Again this can be controlled via CSS.

There is also a point to discuss on the h2 tags you've used here, since they're headings and not entirely appropriate for what you're trying to achieve, but again, in terms of answering this question simply, the fix I've mentioned above will solve the immediate problem, and a recommendation about learning more regarding HTML and CSS is given.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was trying to do something more like this. If Roger and Syd are both selected then instead of listing Roger on one line and then Syd on another line underneath, I just wanted to have --> Roger, Syd (on same line in  a single p tag). But yes now that you mentioned it I realized this is more of an HTML question but the syntax I wanted to use was svelte so I tagged Svelte as well. Thanks for the info! @AntonyJones

Comment: You can use the same technique. Just remove the inner <p> and replace with a <span>